# SynchronizationContext and Async/Await in WinForms

Tags: winforms, async-await

I need help understanding why following Test deadlocks? I suspect it has something to do with `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` that is set as Current `SyncronizationContext` during WinForm control creation.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task myTest()
  {
      //During this winForms control creation, WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext is set as Current SyncronizationContext
      new SomeWinformControl();

      //This statement deadlocks
      await Task.Run(() => { });
  }
```

(MSTest using .NET 4.5.2)

Comment: It has everything to do with Application.Run(), invariably missing in a unit test.  It is the dispatcher loop that is implemented by Run() that keeps async code going.

Comment: @HansPassant, if you create an answer - I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more context to @HansPassant's answer:

> It has everything to do with Application.Run(), invariably missing in
>   a unit test. It is the dispatcher loop that is implemented by Run()
>   that keeps async code going.

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

> Your user interface also has a scheduler: the message pump. A
>   dedicated thread sits in a loop, monitoring a queue of messages and
>   processing each; that loop typically processes messages like mouse
>   events or keyboard events or paint events, but in many frameworks you
>   can also explicitly hand it work to do, e.g. the Control.BeginInvoke
>   method in Windows Forms, or the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method in WPF.

Comment: It would be nice with a bit more of an explanation and a conclusion of how it relates to this specific question instead of just an excerpt from that article.